# What Inserts tab does in MySQL Workbench EER Diagram Table Editing?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I needed to insert some initial (default) data into a new database and I found this Inserts tab on MySQL Workbench EER Diagram table editing form

[image: Table Editing - Inserts]

My assumption was that I can use it to insert initial (default) data that will get propagated to the database during synchronization (not sure how it will get merged with any existing data in the database though...). I added couple rows and synced model with an empty database, but no data was inserted.

So, my question is **what this Inserts tab is for on the Table Editing screen?**

I use MySQL Workbench 6.

P.S. If somebody can also point to an easy way to insert initial (default) data (except simply running a SQL script) I will appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The data added on the INSERTs page is indeed thought to be like an initial set of (test)data. It doesn't consider existing data however. I think it is also only used if you do forward engineering, not on synchronization.

Other ways of inserting data always involve an SQL script, that's what the (text) API is about for SQL servers. But you can add scripts to your model too (see the overview page). They are not run automatically, however.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, the data shows up during forward engineering if "Generate INSERT Statements for Tables" option is checked. Missed this check box the first time.

Comment: What is the behavior for the auto increment `id` field ? Will it start, in your example with `3` for the next insert ?

Comment: Thanks, @NikolaiSamteladze. I was using INSERTs but during forwarding, nothing happens. It's necessary to check "Generate INSERT Statements for Tables".